# How do you randomly sample a radius with a sphere?

Tags: probability

I know that the CDF and pdf for a point uniformly distributed within an n-dimensional sphere of radius $R$ is

$$
F_r(r_0) = \frac{r_0^n}{R^n} \\
f_r(r_0) = n\frac{r_0^{n-1}}{R^{n}}
$$

So for a $3$-dimensional sphere we have $f_r(r_0) = \frac{3r_0^2}{R^{3}}$. Knowing this information, how do I actually choose a random radius subject to this pdf?

Comment: What do you mean by "actually choose a random radius"?

Comment: @uniquesolution By that, I mean how do I sample a radius in accordance to $f_r$.

Comment: Is this actually a question about using a random number generator in a computer program? "How do I sample" doesn't make much sense unless it's some form of "how do I sample this while using only the following tools ... ."

Comment: @DavidK Hmm, so my goal is to write a random number generator for a given PDF, and I would like to experiment with the above pdf for the radius within a sphere.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to sample from the $n$-ball:

1. Sample a point $\bf x$ on the $(n-1)$-sphere.
2. Uniformly sample c ~ U[0,1].
3. Your random radius will be $c^{1/n}$; use this to scale $\bf x$:

$$c^{1/n}\bf x$$

Comment: When you say sample a point x ON the sphere, do you mean on its surface?

Comment: Also, where did the logic come from that the radius should be $c^{1/n}$?

Comment: @user5965026 Yes, that's right: in short, generate a point on the surface, then scale it. For the exponent of $1/n$, consider that the volume $V$ of an $n$-dimensional ball of radius $r$ is $kr^n$ for some constant $k$. That is $$\frac{V(r)}{V(1)} = \frac{kr^n}{k} = r^n.$$

Comment: I understand the volume, but I'm still having a hard time making a connection why taking the inverse root gives the desired outcome.

Comment: I think I got it. It seems to be from inverse transform sampling.

Comment: Right, it's to cancel out the effect of the $r^n$. Consider what happens if you just sample the radius uniformly: you end up with exactly half of your points in a sphere of radius $1/2$, even though that volume is only $1/2^n$ of the total volume.